# running stored procedures automatic in every month

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

hi i've stored procedure with will try to delete data from specified date (sysdate - 30)
and i  wanna trying to run Oracle Stored Procedure in every beginning of month..

how can i do that ?

thanks in advance, sorry for my english

Comment: I'm only familiar with SQL Server, so I did a Google search for "Oracle equivalent of SQL Server Agent" and found this: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090529060948AAUhwpz If it is truly comparable to SQL Server Agent, you can set a job with a schedule that will run automatically.

Comment: Check the Oracle doc for `DBA_JOBS`.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing that could possibly work would be to use the `DBMS_JOB` package.  This, for example, will run `your_procedure` at midnight on the fist of every month starting at midnight on the first of next month and will pass in a parameter of `sysdate - 30`

```
DECLARE 
  l_jobno PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  dbms_job.submit( l_jobno,
                   'BEGIN your_procedure( sysdate - 30 ); END;',
                   add_months( trunc(sysdate,'MM'), 1 ),
                   q'{add_months( trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), 1 )}' );
  commit;
END;
```

You can also use the `DBMS_SCHEDULER` package which is a newer and more sophisticated scheduler assuming you are using a more recent version of Oracle.  That can get much more sophisticated and much more involved than `DBMS_JOB`-- if your requirements are really simply, though, the lighter weight `DBMS_JOB` may be easier to learn and understand.

Answer (score 0):

Minor note:

Oracle recommends that you switch from DBMS_JOB to Oracle Scheduler.

```
BEGIN                      
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB ( 
   job_name        => 'your_job_name',
   job_type        => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',       -- see oracle documentation on types --
   job_action      => 'name of the procedure',
   start_date      => trunc(sysdate)+2/24,      -- every night @ 2 a.m.
   repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=2',    -- daily @ 2 a.m.
   end_date        => NULL,
   enabled         => TRUE,
   comments        => 'your general comment');
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

you can schedule a job for it,..you have to call the stored procedure in the job.So that you can run the stored procedure  in the beginning of every month..